# set timezone of logging messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

Is there a way to configure logback in spring boot to output the local time of the log messages in a different timezone than the system timezone?

I would like to set it up over configuration (i.e. application.yml / overwrite with environment variables on specific systems)

Comment: Please try this in the property file. logging.pattern.dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS,Australia/Perth

Comment: Would be cool, but seems not to have any effect :(

Comment: Can you provide logback.xml, you are using and yaml configuration?. Above suggestion should work. Here is working pattern for me.
`%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, Australia/Perth} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n`.
By default logback tries to use zone from JVM so you can control JVM zone using `-Duser.timezone=Australia/Perth` environment variable. However, this will also affect your code logic where you are using get time.

Answer (score 11):

Just add to your application.yml following lines:

```yaml
logging:
  pattern:
    dateformat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Europe/Moscow
```

The corresponding environment variable is LOGGING_PATTERN_DATEFORMAT